# Entity Framework performance between include(string) and include(x=>x.myType)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I know that we can now (from EF5 ?) use

```
var employees = Db.Employees.Include("Details").Include("Details.DetailsType"))
```

instead of

```
var employees = Db.Employees.Include(x => x.Details).Include(x => x.Details.Select(y => y.DetailsType))
```

With the Debug, the tho queries seems to be exactly the same so i was wondering myself a couple of questions :

- What are the difference between this two usages?
- Is there a difference of performance between this two lines?
- What is the best practice, which one should i use corresponding to which situation?

Thanks for your answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the difference between this two usages?

One uses a string, the other not. SO one does not throw a compile error if the property is renamed, the other does.

> Is there a difference of performance between this two lines?

The string is marginally faster, IIRC. Less reflection lookups to find what is meant. I think the second form dynamically gets the string.

> What is the best practice, which one should i use corresponding to
>   which situation?

Always the non-string version because of the difference described in the first part - if you rename the property, then this can automatically be corrected and found, while this is not the case in the string form.

Quite obvious actually when you think about it. As well as - ah - documented.